# ffmpeg -ss and -to commands encoding via API calls

Tags: ffmpeg

When calling ffmpeg from the dll's how do I achieve the following:

C:\ffmpeg\bin>ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -ss 00:20:20 -to 00:30:00 -c co
py test.mp4

What API's methods do I need to call?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you asking is about `av_seek_frame()`.

Check these:
https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__decoding.html#gaa23f7619d8d4ea0857065d9979c75ac8

https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/api-seek-test_8c_source.html#l00174